# Ошибка при сборке react-native приложения. 502 ошибка при запросе maven

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сервис **dl.bintray** недоступен. Буквально пару дней назад сборка происходила успешно, но теперь проблема. Может ли кто-то объяснить, зачем при сборке запрашивается этот ресурс и как можно обойтись без него, так как он возвращает ***502*** код.

Comment: bintray все. меняйте repositories в build.gradle на другие. google и проч.

Comment: А с какого момента он все? Можно где-то почитать? 6 декабря еще все работало вроде как.

https://status.jfrog.io/ тут у них кстати, написано, что как раз они проводят какие-то работы, если я не ошибаюсь

**UPD: This means by the end of March 2021, publishing new packages to Bintray will no longer be allowed. Existing packages can still be downloaded until February 1st 2022. After that, projects that have dependencies hosted in JCenter will fail fetching packages and stop compiling.**

Вроде как должы только после февраля 2022 года все

Comment: Работало, но уже пару раз ломалось, тоже сборки вставали. до кучи jcenter задепрекейтили, он сейчас в ридонли режиме. в общем надо перетекать на другие репо

Comment: А что это вообще за репы такие? Проект достался мне от других разработчиков, манагеры требует срочно релизить, а тут такая ошибка странная.

Comment: Ну просто грохнуть bintray из repositories, посмотреть соберется или нет. Большинство либ переехали с бинтрея давно, mavenCentral, google или гитхабовский репо работают и там все должно быть. Если какая-то уж совсем легаси либа подключена, искать ее, где она еще может быть, вплоть до того, чтоб ее в libs руками положить...
С реактом точно проблем быть не должно

Comment: Понял. Да, я убирал и собиралось нормально. Но, я не думал, что это показатель, и боялся что, что-то все ровно сломается. Я по коммитам поглядел, эта строка была добавлена для пуш уведомлений. Спасибо